# SyntaxError - Bubble Sort

Tags: python

```
# Bubble Sort
def sort(arr):
    while True:
        corrected = False
        for i in range(0, len(arr) - 1):
            if arr[i] > arr[i+1]:
                arr[i], arr[i+1] = arr[i+1], arr[i]
                corrected = True
        if not corrected:
                return arr

print sort([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
print sort([4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 99])
print sort([6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1])
```

I am getting the following error: Please help.

```
/Users/tanujraitaneja/PycharmProjects/Giraffe/venv/bin/python /Users/tanujraitaneja/Library/Preferences/PyCharmCE2018.2/scratches/scratch.py
  File "/Users/tanujraitaneja/Library/Preferences/PyCharmCE2018.2/scratches/scratch.py", line 11
    print sort([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
         ^
**SyntaxError: invalid syntax**

**Process finished with exit code 1**
```

Comment: which version of python are you using? if you are using python 3.* you should use print with parentheses : print(sort([6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]))

Comment: Are you using Python 3? Then it's `print(sort([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]))`, with parentheses for the print function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using python 3? Then you need to wrap your function call inside ()

```
print(sort([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]))
print(sort([4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 99]))
print(sort([6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]))
```